# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I'v got the following problem:
I tried to create a simple Servlep with Eclipse:

```
@WebServlet(description = "Adress book servlet", urlPatterns = {"/new_address"})
public class CAddressBookServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public CAddressBookServlet() 
    {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {}
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {}
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

And it works fine with Tomcat!
But then I was to add Hibernate functionality into my project. I add just one line to servlet contructor:

```
@WebServlet(description = "Adress book servlet", urlPatterns = {"/new_address"})
public class CAddressBookServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public CAddressBookServlet() 
    {
        super();
        new AnnotationConfiguration();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {}
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {}
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Which cause the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.servlets.CAddressBookServlet
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.servlets.CAddressBookServlet
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.servlets.CAddressBookServlet
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
>     org.servlets.CAddressBookServlet.(CAddressBookServlet.java:33)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     org.servlets.CAddressBookServlet.(CAddressBookServlet.java:33)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.33 logs.

How can I make hibernate working with my servlet?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Hibernate libraries from your deployed  web app.

Comment: her you go. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception)

Answer (score 2):

@Perception has the right answer. You need to include the Hibernate libraries with your deployed war file. You can put them in WEB-INF/lib or in the Tomcat endorsed directory. I prefer the WEB-INF/lib location, so you don't interfere with any other applications on the server.

Comment: Thanks, that's really matter. I add all the content of my User Library to WEB-INF/lib folder and the problem was solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikhailZimka If this answer solved your issue, please upvote it (click the up-pointing triangle above the votes for this answer) and then "accept" it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the annotations jar.
[Download the Annotations](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final/hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar)

Copy the downloaded jar file to one of these locations....

```
 -> Tomcat lib directory
          or
 -> To the folder webapps/< your_project >/WEB-INF/lib
```

And restart the server

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunatly
Moreover I have a library in my project build path containg hibernate-annotation.jar file. That's not a reason.