# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, hibernate

I've created a web dynamic project, and want to use `Hibernate` with it.

Then, I used the `Hibernate Code Generation` to generate classes code, and I created a class `HibernateUtil` where I initialize `SessionFactory`.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
        try{
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                    new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

And another class `HibernateSessionFactoryListener` :

```
public class HibernateSessionFactoryListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println("\n Context Initilaise \n");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        System.out.println("\n Context Detruit \n");
    }

}
```

When I run my project I get this error message :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactoryListener.contextInitialized(HibernateSessionFactoryListener.java:12)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 12 more
```

How can I solve this problem ?

## Edit 1 :

This is my Java Build Path :

[image]

Comment: DO you have the class in your classpath ?

Comment: PLease add the hibernate jar onto your class path .. That should solve the problem. Which is the version of hibernate you are using ?

Comment: @ArunM I did added hibernate jar to my project build path, please check the modification I made to my post

Comment: I think the problem is that the hibernate JARS are not part of your web app libraries. Please check you WAR to see if the hibernate core jar is available in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Do check in your lib. Jar required at run time.

Comment: I guess u are missing hibernate jar.....

Comment: @ArunM Okey thanks, I solved that problem, it was because I added Hibernate libraries in the Java Build Path instead of adding them into the lib folder.

Comment: your solution might be here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Hibernate 3.6, “org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration” is deprecated, and all its functionality has been moved to “org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration“.
So , you can safely replace your “AnnotationConfiguration” with “Configuration” class

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-the-type-annotationconfiguration-is-deprecated/

Comment: I changed it in my -servlet.xml file. Got rid of that error!