# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.10.0.final

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

I'm trying to use Hibernate with jasperreports, using jasersoft studio (6.10.0),

I'm using hibernate 5 in my project, so I'm using annotations to map classes.

When I'm creating the Hibernate Data Adapter, I chose to use "Annotations" but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration cannot be found by 
net.sf.jasperreports_6.10.0.final
```

Am I missing some jar files?

Comment: Note hibernate is an optional dependance of jasper report, please check that first that you have hibernate in class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Hibernate 3.6, “org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration” is
>   deprecated, and all its functionality has been moved to
>   “org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration“.
>
> So , you can safely replace your “AnnotationConfiguration” with
>   “Configuration” class.

Taken from [Hibernate – The type AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-the-type-annotationconfiguration-is-deprecated/)

In practical terms, it means you need to use other version of jasperreports that doesn't use deprecated API or downgrade Hibernate.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850005/5292302) and as information [jasper reports 6.10](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.10.0) have Hibernate 5.4.1.Final as a dependency. Hence it does not in itself use deprecated api and it is the latest version, hence "need to use other version" is not a feasible answer. Furthermore deprecated methods do not throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @PetterFriberg `Furthermore deprecated methods do not throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. This is not correct. Simply write a method that throws `ClassNotFoundException` when it doesn't find its dependency and annotate it a `@Deprecated`.