# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException for hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to set up a web application with tomcat 7.0, java6 and hibernate 4.

Basically, you can say I have the same problem as in this thread: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception) , but I'm not able to solve it. I have checked build path, and everything else I've been able to think of.

So, when trying to have the servlet use the hibernate objects, I get this error:

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class controller.ControlServlet

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
controller.SearchCommand.<init>(SearchCommand.java:25)
controller.ControlServlet.<init>(ControlServlet.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

SearchCommand:

```
public class SearchCommand implements Command{
private BookingDAO dao;

public SearchCommand(){
    this.dao = new BookingDAO(); // line 25
}
```

ControlServlet:

```
    public ControlServlet() {
    super();

     commands.put("search", new SearchCommand());

}
```

BookingDAO:

```
public class BookingDAO {
private SessionFactory factory;

public BookingDAO(){
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public void getHotel(Booking booking, int hotelId){
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Hotel hotel = (Hotel) session.get(Hotel.class, hotelId);
        booking.setHotel(hotel);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Classpath:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1S2a.jpg

Can anyone help me?

Comment: check if you have all those needed jars inside your war file.

Comment: Not altering the buildpath, but copying them all to WEB-INF/lib helped for some reason...