# Hibernate Servlet Configuration and Working

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlets

Can anyone help me out to configuring hibernate-4.3.7 in jbossAS-7.1 server and help me in working with it in eclipse i am getting this exception i have generated configuration.xml file as well as mapping.xml file for my Class

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
   org.login.Login.doPost(Login.java:45)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Comment: Make sure you have `Hibernate.jar` in the project library. This question is already asked here [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188542/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hibernateexception)

Comment: The type ServiceRegistryBuilder is deprecated                                                          i am getting this error in the HibernateUtilities file and its preventing from creating serviceregistery

Comment: From the above, the root cause of `ExceptionInInitializerError ` is `NullPointerException` in `HibernateUtilities` class. You should debug your code & find at which point u r getting `null` value.

Comment: thak you both its working now